# How to quick select & edit a table cell content on wordpress html

Tags: html, wordpress, tablecell

I stumbled onto a problem recently when selecting and edit the table content in wordpress.

Simply put:

- The content in the table cell is too big to drag scroll and select
  them all
- I can't select the entire cell like back then, there was a
  trick that is select the space after "dictum leo." below and drag to
  the next cell.
- -> But now if I do that both cells are selected,    there's no way to select one.

It slowed down my productivity for precise work and I don't know where to ask, honestly.
Hope you guys can help.
Thanks for reading,

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr style="height: 21px;"><td style="width: 277px; height: 21px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000;" width="100%">Header1</td><td style="width: 277px; height: 21px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000;" width="100%"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue vitae risus in luctus. Morbi congue id quam at ornare. Quisque pulvinar aliquam urna congue finibus. Donec eu lacus elit. Duis urna nulla, sodales id hendrerit in, pellentesque non nisi. Vivamus et tincidunt justo. Nam condimentum id ex eget efficitur. Duis eget fringilla quam. In semper faucibus urna, sed porttitor nibh rhoncus quis. Duis non ullamcorper mi. Curabitur vehicula ipsum ac tortor consectetur malesuada. Nam ornare mi quis turpis fermentum, id consequat nibh facilisis. Nullam eu lorem ut turpis hendrerit placerat sit amet eu arcu.</p><p>Sed sed blandit tellus. Fusce interdum ultrices ex eu vestibulum. Fusce efficitur auctor ultricies. Praesent imperdiet nunc ex, eu accumsan quam feugiat vitae. Mauris sed faucibus quam. Donec sit amet sodales sem, eget facilisis erat. Praesent diam metus, ullamcorper sit amet odio a, tristique bibendum libero. Fusce dictum, enim ut consequat convallis, arcu turpis viverra arcu, et rhoncus neque ante at leo. Vestibulum non libero vehicula, dapibus enim vitae, viverra eros. Praesent pulvinar, est quis euismod gravida, nunc sem congue lacus, ac vulputate libero elit sit amet justo. Phasellus tincidunt convallis elit, id aliquam nisl facilisis eget.</p><p>Duis et ipsum in felis dignissim eleifend eget vitae odio. Proin in leo a diam elementum dictum sit amet sed turpis. Cras nunc leo, varius eget tincidunt et, aliquam ut ligula. Quisque fermentum leo porttitor, vulputate sem molestie, lacinia turpis. Morbi efficitur, tortor non pretium tempor, lorem risus eleifend felis, at sollicitudin sem dolor et elit. Sed nec ornare neque. Cras lectus ipsum, malesuada sit amet pharetra ac, bibendum eget lorem. Vestibulum in luctus augue, vitae placerat metus. Fusce et elit ac massa aliquam mattis. Aliquam efficitur tempor pharetra. Proin congue nulla dolor, luctus consequat tellus porttitor ac.</p><p>Donec eu odio vel turpis varius vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras pulvinar sodales malesuada. Phasellus tempor dolor ipsum, vitae feugiat diam rutrum vitae. Suspendisse ultrices orci vel nisl blandit, eget fermentum metus ultricies. Donec bibendum gravida magna, eget maximus urna lacinia quis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sollicitudin, diam ac auctor vestibulum, est diam hendrerit arcu, nec facilisis quam orci eu magna. Pellentesque et pharetra risus, eget hendrerit turpis. Aenean consectetur augue sit amet eros ultricies lacinia. Aenean vel nisl at neque varius consectetur nec id libero. Nam pharetra commodo metus in pulvinar. Vivamus vel dictum leo.</p></td></tr><tr style="height: 21px;"><td style="width: 277px; height: 21px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000;" width="100%">Header2</td><td style="width: 277px; height: 21px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000;" width="100%"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue vitae risus in luctus. Morbi congue id quam at ornare. Quisque pulvinar aliquam urna congue finibus. Donec eu lacus elit. Duis urna nulla, sodales id hendrerit in, pellentesque non nisi. Vivamus et tincidunt justo. Nam condimentum id ex eget efficitur. Duis eget fringilla quam. In semper faucibus urna, sed porttitor nibh rhoncus quis. Duis non ullamcorper mi. Curabitur vehicula ipsum ac tortor consectetur malesuada. Nam ornare mi quis turpis fermentum, id consequat nibh facilisis. Nullam eu lorem ut turpis hendrerit placerat sit amet eu arcu.</p><p>Sed sed blandit tellus. Fusce interdum ultrices ex eu vestibulum. Fusce efficitur auctor ultricies. Praesent imperdiet nunc ex, eu accumsan quam feugiat vitae. Mauris sed faucibus quam. Donec sit amet sodales sem, eget facilisis erat. Praesent diam metus, ullamcorper sit amet odio a, tristique bibendum libero. Fusce dictum, enim ut consequat convallis, arcu turpis viverra arcu, et rhoncus neque ante at leo. Vestibulum non libero vehicula, dapibus enim vitae, viverra eros. Praesent pulvinar, est quis euismod gravida, nunc sem congue lacus, ac vulputate libero elit sit amet justo. Phasellus tincidunt convallis elit, id aliquam nisl facilisis eget.</p><p>Duis et ipsum in felis dignissim eleifend eget vitae odio. Proin in leo a diam elementum dictum sit amet sed turpis. Cras nunc leo, varius eget tincidunt et, aliquam ut ligula. Quisque fermentum leo porttitor, vulputate sem molestie, lacinia turpis. Morbi efficitur, tortor non pretium tempor, lorem risus eleifend felis, at sollicitudin sem dolor et elit. Sed nec ornare neque. Cras lectus ipsum, malesuada sit amet pharetra ac, bibendum eget lorem. Vestibulum in luctus augue, vitae placerat metus. Fusce et elit ac massa aliquam mattis. Aliquam efficitur tempor pharetra. Proin congue nulla dolor, luctus consequat tellus porttitor ac.</p><p>Donec eu odio vel turpis varius vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras pulvinar sodales malesuada. Phasellus tempor dolor ipsum, vitae feugiat diam rutrum vitae. Suspendisse ultrices orci vel nisl blandit, eget fermentum metus ultricies. Donec bibendum gravida magna, eget maximus urna lacinia quis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sollicitudin, diam ac auctor vestibulum, est diam hendrerit arcu, nec facilisis quam orci eu magna. Pellentesque et pharetra risus, eget hendrerit turpis. Aenean consectetur augue sit amet eros ultricies lacinia. Aenean vel nisl at neque varius consectetur nec id libero. Nam pharetra commodo metus in pulvinar. Vivamus vel dictum leo.</p></td></tr><tr style="height: 21px;"><td style="width: 277px; height: 21px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000;" width="100%">Header3</td><td style="width: 277px; height: 21px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000;" width="100%"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue vitae risus in luctus. Morbi congue id quam at ornare. Quisque pulvinar aliquam urna congue finibus. Donec eu lacus elit. Duis urna nulla, sodales id hendrerit in, pellentesque non nisi. Vivamus et tincidunt justo. Nam condimentum id ex eget efficitur. Duis eget fringilla quam. In semper faucibus urna, sed porttitor nibh rhoncus quis. Duis non ullamcorper mi. Curabitur vehicula ipsum ac tortor consectetur malesuada. Nam ornare mi quis turpis fermentum, id consequat nibh facilisis. Nullam eu lorem ut turpis hendrerit placerat sit amet eu arcu.</p><p>Sed sed blandit tellus. Fusce interdum ultrices ex eu vestibulum. Fusce efficitur auctor ultricies. Praesent imperdiet nunc ex, eu accumsan quam feugiat vitae. Mauris sed faucibus quam. Donec sit amet sodales sem, eget facilisis erat. Praesent diam metus, ullamcorper sit amet odio a, tristique bibendum libero. Fusce dictum, enim ut consequat convallis, arcu turpis viverra arcu, et rhoncus neque ante at leo. Vestibulum non libero vehicula, dapibus enim vitae, viverra eros. Praesent pulvinar, est quis euismod gravida, nunc sem congue lacus, ac vulputate libero elit sit amet justo. Phasellus tincidunt convallis elit, id aliquam nisl facilisis eget.</p><p>Duis et ipsum in felis dignissim eleifend eget vitae odio. Proin in leo a diam elementum dictum sit amet sed turpis. Cras nunc leo, varius eget tincidunt et, aliquam ut ligula. Quisque fermentum leo porttitor, vulputate sem molestie, lacinia turpis. Morbi efficitur, tortor non pretium tempor, lorem risus eleifend felis, at sollicitudin sem dolor et elit. Sed nec ornare neque. Cras lectus ipsum, malesuada sit amet pharetra ac, bibendum eget lorem. Vestibulum in luctus augue, vitae placerat metus. Fusce et elit ac massa aliquam mattis. Aliquam efficitur tempor pharetra. Proin congue nulla dolor, luctus consequat tellus porttitor ac.</p><p>Donec eu odio vel turpis varius vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras pulvinar sodales malesuada. Phasellus tempor dolor ipsum, vitae feugiat diam rutrum vitae. Suspendisse ultrices orci vel nisl blandit, eget fermentum metus ultricies. Donec bibendum gravida magna, eget maximus urna lacinia quis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sollicitudin, diam ac auctor vestibulum, est diam hendrerit arcu, nec facilisis quam orci eu magna. Pellentesque et pharetra risus, eget hendrerit turpis. Aenean consectetur augue sit amet eros ultricies lacinia. Aenean vel nisl at neque varius consectetur nec id libero. Nam pharetra commodo metus in pulvinar. Vivamus vel dictum leo.</p></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: On what device? A mobile device? Desktop? This question is unclear to me what you're actually asking.

Comment: On desktop, wordpress provides a word like ui to edit the table, the problem is drag and select the cell content is slow and in accurate. I want to know if there's a way to select the entire cell like ctrl+a but just the cell.

Comment: You can highlight the first word, scroll to the end of the text you want to select, press shift button and click at the end of the text. This will select it all.

Comment: Well that's one way to do it just slightly better than the manual drag select, but the format is still there and must be removed manually. Is there anyway else, without scrolling? Like back then i could just drag the mouse between cells and it will select the entire cell. This old method ignore the format as well.

Scrolling is bad when the content is big, it's like the example i put above. You need to know if you scrolled at the end of the cell yet or it's from another cell.